# The string is missing terminator: ' . Batch

Tags: powershell, batch-file

```
@echo off
color 2
echo UWP Helper & echo.

:begin
echo 1. Install game
echo 2. Install DLC
echo 3. Enable Developer Mode
echo 4. Disable Developer Mode
echo 5. Exit

set /p action="Choose action: "

IF NOT "%action%" == "1" ( IF NOT "%action%" == "2" ( IF NOT "%action%" == "3" ( IF NOT "%action%" == "4" ( IF NOT "%action%" == "5" (  goto begin ) ) ) ) )

IF "%action%" == "1" ( goto gameinstall )
IF "%action%" == "2" ( goto dlcinstall )
IF "%action%" == "3" ( goto developeron )
IF "%action%" == "4" ( goto developeroff )
IF "%action%" == "5" ( goto exit )

:developeron
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock" /t REG_DWORD /f /v "AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense" /d "1"
goto begin

:developeroff
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock" /t REG_DWORD /f /v "AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense" /d "0"
goto begin

:gameinstall
set file_check="%~dp0AppxSignature.p7x"
set file_check_new="AppxSignature.tmp"

IF EXIST %file_check% ( REN %file_check% %file_check_new% )

powershell Add-AppxPackage '%~dp0AppxManifest.xml' -Register
goto begin

:dlcinstall
set dlc_directory="%~dp0MicrosoftStore_DLC\\"
set dlc_pattern=AppxManifest.xml
set sign_pattern=*.p7x
set file_check_new="AppxSignature.tmp"

IF EXIST %dlc_directory% ( cd %dlc_directory% )

IF EXIST %dlc_directory% ( FOR /R %%I in (%sign_pattern%) DO IF EXIST "%%I" ( REN "%%I" %file_check_new% ) ) ELSE ( echo DLC directory does not exist. )

IF EXIST %dlc_directory% ( FOR /R %%I in (%dlc_pattern%) DO IF EXIST "%%I" ( powershell Add-AppxPackage '%%I' -Register ) ) ELSE ( echo DLC directory does not exist. )

IF EXIST %dlc_directory% ( cd .. )
goto begin

:exit
```

i am keep having this same error and i have no idea what is causing it. Also this is not my code but issue won't be resolved by creator. Can someone please fix this because i lack technical knowledge

The string is missing the terminator: '.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

Comment: The first question I'd ask is why you are using `set /p` for user single key input entry when there is already a dedicated Windows command utility for that, _(`choice.exe`)_? Next, why are there two trailing backward slashes assigned to the `dlc_directory` variable value? Also can you not use the full and proper PowerShell commands, (```%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Add-AppxPackage -Path '%~dp0AppxManifest.xml' -Register"```)?

Comment: Good tips, @Compo, but note that `-NoLogo` is redundant when you either pass a command (`-Command`) or a script path (`-File`) to the PowerShell CLI (the only exception is if you precede `-File` _with `-NoExit`_).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are good incidental recommendations for improving your code in the comments, but as for your main problem:

> The string is missing the terminator: '

This error message implies that the command you're passing to `powershell.exe`  contains an opening `'` that isn't matched by a closing one; you can provoke the error as follows from `cmd.exe` / a batch file:

```bash
:: This produces the error above.
:: Parameter -Command (-c) implied.
powershell 'ab
```

With respect to your batch file - assuming that it is the full code that manifests your problem - this implies that one of the following commands causes the problem:

```bash
powershell Add-AppxPackage '%~dp0AppxManifest.xml' -Register
powershell Add-AppxPackage '%%I' -Register
```

This in turn **implies that what `%~dp0` or `%%I` *expands to* happens to contain `'` characters *itself***, i.e. the executing batch file's directory path contains `'` or the directory path of at least one of the `AppxManifest.xml` files in that directory's subtree contains `'`, which breaks the syntax of the `'...'` PowerShell string (in order to *embed* a `'` in a `'...'` string, it must be escaped as `''`).

The **easiest solution is to use `"..."` quoting** instead, which **requires escaping the `"` characters as `\"`** (sic); also, it's worth enclosing the *entire* command in (unescaped) `"..."` and using the `-NoProfile` switch to prevent unnecessary loading of profile files, and, for conceptual clarity, making the positionally implied `-Command` argument a *named* one (not least because `pwsh.exe`, the *PowerShell (Core) 7+* CLI now *requires* `-Command` (`-c`)):

```bash
powershell -NoProfile -Command "Add-AppxPackage \"%~dp0AppxManifest.xml\" -Register"
powershell -NoProfile -Command "Add-AppxPackage \"%%I\" -Register"
```